# Symfony 5.4 Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation \"X\" does not exist

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine

I have really weird situation. What can be important i increased version symfony (and all what i had to in composer.json) to 5.4 from 4.4. Each call in controller which i do for example:

```
 public function indexAction(LegalSentenceRepository $userRepository): Response
    {

        var_dump($userRepository->getAll());
        return $this->render('base.html.twig');
    }

<?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\LegalSentence;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @method LegalSentence|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method LegalSentence|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method LegalSentence[]    findAll()
 * @method LegalSentence[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
class LegalSentenceRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, LegalSentence::class);
    }

    public function getLegalSentenceQuery()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ls');
        $qb->select('ls');

        return $qb;
    }

    public function getAll(): ?LegalSentence
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult()
        ;
    }

}


<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\LegalSentenceRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="legal_sentences")
 */
class LegalSentence implements EntityToArrayRest
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="legal_sentence_id")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=80, nullable=true, name="legal_sentence_code")
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=80, name="legal_sentence_name")
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", name="legal_sentence_content", nullable=true)
     */
    private $content;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", name="legal_sentence_default", options={"default": 0})
     */
    private $isDefault = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="legal_sentence_sequence", options={"default": 0})
     */
    private $sequence;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\OrderHistory", mappedBy="sentence")
     */
    private $orderHistories;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Order", mappedBy="legalSentences")
     */
    private $orders;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\OrderPage", mappedBy="legalSentences")
     */
    private $orderPages;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->orders = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->orderHistories = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->orderPages = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent($content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->code;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $code
     */
    public function setCode($code): void
    {
        $this->code = $code;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSequence()
    {
        return $this->sequence;
    }

    /**
     * @param $sequence
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setSequence($sequence)
    {
        $this->sequence = $sequence;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function isDefault()
    {
        return $this->isDefault;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $isDefault
     */
    public function setIsDefault($isDefault): void
    {
        $this->isDefault = $isDefault;
    }


    public function toArrayRest()
    {
        return [
          'id' => $this->getId(),
          'code' => $this->getCode(),
          'name' => $this->getName(),
          'content' => $this->getContent(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|OrderHistory[]
     */
    public function getOrderHistories(): Collection
    {
        return $this->orderHistories;
    }

    public function addOrderHistory(OrderHistory $orderHistory): self
    {
        if (!$this->orderHistories->contains($orderHistory)) {
            $this->orderHistories[] = $orderHistory;
            $orderHistory->setSentence($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeOrderHistory(OrderHistory $orderHistory): self
    {
        if ($this->orderHistories->contains($orderHistory)) {
            $this->orderHistories->removeElement($orderHistory);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($orderHistory->getSentence() === $this) {
                $orderHistory->setSentence(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Order[]
     */
    public function getOrders(): Collection
    {
        return $this->orders;
    }

    public function addOrder(Order $order): self
    {
        if (!$this->orders->contains($order)) {
            $this->orders[] = $order;
            $order->addLegalSentence($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeOrder(Order $order): self
    {
        if ($this->orders->contains($order)) {
            $this->orders->removeElement($order);
            $order->removeLegalSentence($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|OrderPage[]
     */
    public function getOrderPages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->orderPages;
    }

    public function addOrderPage(OrderPage $orderPage): self
    {
        if (!$this->orderPages->contains($orderPage)) {
            $this->orderPages[] = $orderPage;
            $orderPage->addLegalSentence($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeOrderPage(OrderPage $orderPage): self
    {
        if ($this->orderPages->contains($orderPage)) {
            $this->orderPages->removeElement($orderPage);
            $orderPage->removeLegalSentence($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

THe most weird thing is that when i got error :

```
{"code":500,"message":"An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT l0_.legal_sentence_id AS legal_sentence_id_0, l0_.legal_sentence_code AS legal_sentence_code_1, l0_.legal_sentence_name AS legal_sentence_name_2, l0_.legal_sentence_content AS legal_sentence_content_3, l0_.legal_sentence_default AS legal_sentence_default_4, l0_.legal_sentence_sequence AS legal_sentence_sequence_5 FROM legal_sentences l0_':\n\nSQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation \"legal_sentences\" does not exist\nLINE 1: ...ntence_sequence AS legal_sentence_sequence_5 FROM legal_sent...\n                                                             ^"}
```

And i will take that SQL and run that on DB then it works without any problem. I did not check all Repositories but all which i did got this problem.

Does anybody know what is going on? I have checked as well preview DB and there are on 99% all connections.

DB is mysql.

I removed DB and recreate that from scratch with all migrations.
I have checked if i have DB connection and tables are there.
I reinstall all composer dependencies.